# Need help writing a Makefile that creates all the objective files into a new subdir

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to make a Makefile for a big project.
The project structure is *(I've ommitted the header files)*:

```
root/feature1/feat1.c
root/feature2/feat2.c
root/srcfile1.c
root/srcfile2.c
```

I wanted to start easy so I created a simpler project with the source files in the root dir.
I need to create all the object files in one directory, let's say, **objdir**.
The project structure of the simple project is:

```
root/main.c
root/word.c
```

By looking in other questions I have come up with this:

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -c
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p
OUT = words
OBJDIR = objdir
SRCDIR = .
_OBJS = main.o word.o
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJS))


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

all: directories program

directories: ${OBJDIR}

${OBJDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${OBJDIR}

program: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

When running it with `make -f ./myMakefile all` (changed the filename as in the same dir, there is Netbeans' Makefile), I am getting this output:

```
gcc -o objdir/main.o main.c
/tmp/ccatfAHu.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `CreateWord'
main.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `CreateWord'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [objdir/main.o] Error 1
```

Giving the `make all` command, it tries to produce the targes `directories` and `program`. 
The dir `objdir` is created and in it, there are the `main.o` and `word.o` files.

What am I doing wrong with the makefile of the simpleproject?

**EDIT:**
Added the `-c` flag at the `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` rule.
Removed the `$(FLAGS)` from $`(CC) -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS) $(LIBS)`.
Now, if we move to my project problem, I need to access all the source files from all the directories:

1. `/repo-root`
2. `/repo-root/feature1/feat1.c`
3. `/repo-root/feature2/feat2.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this rule:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

you're missing the `-c` flag. Instead of building an object file, Make is trying to build an *executable* named `objdir/main.o`, and `main.c` doesn't have all of the needed code. Just do this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the Makefile I've posted to reflect the changes I've made. Also, added the actual question for my project. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @Chris: Generally, one Question should contain one question. But it's quite easy to handle sources in different directories using [VPATH and vpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#source files to compile relative to the src dir
CSOURCE =  main.c
CSOURCE +=  func1.c
SRCDIR = .
vpath %.c $(SRCDIR)/
CC = gcc
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p
OBJDIR = objdir
BINDIR = bindir
#list of objects
OBJS    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(CSOURCE:.c=.o))
#output name for executable
APP = example


all: ${OBJDIR} $(OBJS) bin

#rule to create bin and objects dir
${BINDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${BINDIR}

${OBJDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${OBJDIR}

#rule to compile c files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

#to create executable
bin: $(BINDIR) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o  $(BINDIR)/$(APP)

#to clean executable and objects
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your solution? Also, does this, provide a solution for the simple project or my project (with `feature1` and `feature2` directories)?

Comment: you need to add one makefile for each directory, call all makefiles from the root makefile.

Comment: And all of these Makefiles will place their objective files in the same dir, right? 
So I will have to create a rule for each directory, that calls the respective Makefile, is that correct? Could you post an example of how the targets and rules would be?

Answer (score 0):

Updated root make file, Use this in the root/ directory

```
WORKDIR = $(shell pwd)
MODULES = feature1 feature2
CSOURCE =  main.c
CSOURCE +=  func1.c
SRCDIR = .
vpath %.c $(SRCDIR)/
CC = gcc
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p
OBJDIR = $(WORKDIR)/objdir
BINDIR = $(WORKDIR)/bindir
OBJS    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(CSOURCE:.c=.o))
APP = example

all: ${OBJDIR} modules $(OBJS) bin

modules:
    for mod in $(MODULES); do \
      echo "Building $$mod ....."; \
      $(MAKE) -C $(WORKDIR)/$$mod all; \
    done

${BINDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${BINDIR}

${OBJDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${OBJDIR}

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

bin: $(BINDIR) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/*.o -o  $(BINDIR)/$(APP)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)
```

feature make file, use this in the root/feature1 directory and root/feature2 directory

```
WORKDIR = $(shell cd ..; pwd)
CSOURCE =  func2.c
SRCDIR = .
vpath %.c $(SRCDIR)/
CC = gcc
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p
OBJDIR = $(WORKDIR)/objdir
OBJS    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(CSOURCE:.c=.o))

all: ${OBJDIR} $(OBJS) 

${OBJDIR}:
    ${MKDIR_P} ${OBJDIR}

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(OBJDIR)
```

When you want to add new directory say feature3, you can just add it in main makefile module list and copy the feature1 makefile to feature3 and update source file list

Hope this helps